# turn around the book VS turn over the book

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> - Turn around the book! You are reading it upside down.
> - Turn over the book so that you can see the price.

Are "**turn around**" and **"turn over**" used correctly in these contexts?

Comment: "Turn the book round" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Turn around = rotate, Turn over = flip